# Aurelia - DevTools failed to parse SourceMap

Tags: asp.net-core, aurelia, babeljs, source-maps

Since upgrading to Chrome 71, my team has experience an issue with Chrome not being able to parse our SourceMaps. I'm currently on Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit).

The 3 failing maps are:

1. vendor-bundle.js.map
2. app-bundle.js.map
3. bootstrap.css.map

Details:

- ASP.NET Core 2.1
- It is an Aurelia app using Babel compiler
- Sourcemaps are turned on for "dev & stage"
- "sourceMap" is set to true in .babelrc
- using gulp-sourcemaps
- "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4"

We are quite sure that the only variable that changed was upgrading from Chrome version 70 to 71 because we tried the same code in each version of the browser. Since we have restarted Chrome and it has auto-updated, we all have noticed that source maps fail once upgraded to version 71.

I have been following this seemingly related thread on GitHub
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8506

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The sourcemaps randomly started working again. We're assuming it is due to something Chrome did.